# dimension of that vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I would like to know how to prove that the dimension  of $L(E,E)$ (that is the set of linear maps from  $E\rightarrow E$) where $E$ is a finite dimensional vector space ($dim E=n$). I know that the dimension is $n^2$ but I do not know how to prove it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

let us consider a basis $e_i$, $i=1\ldots n$ of $E$, and an element $A\in L(E,E)$.

$A$ is caracterized via $A(e_1)\ldots A(e_n)$ who are elements of
$E$, and so

$$
A(e_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{i,j}e_j
$$

So the elements $E_{i,j}\in L(E,E)$ defined by
$$\begin{array}{lll}
E_{i,j} (e_k)&=& e_j \text{  if }i=k\\
&=&0\text{ otherwise}\end{array}$$
is a family of cardinal $n^2$ and who generates $L(E,E)$.

Hence $\dim L(E,E)\leq n^2<\infty$.

Comment: we meet again so soon!+1!

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, Let us consider $f\in L(E,E)$ and let $(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)$ be a basis for $E$ then every $x\in E$ can be written as $x=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i}e_{i}$ since $f\in L(E,E)$ then $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i}f(e_{i})$ ...then I am lost

Comment: ok, but what are the components of those vectors $A(e_i)$ please?

Comment: Ok I see it's just the column of the matrix $B=(A(e_1),...A(e_n))$ that is $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, but why the elements $E_{i,j}$ you mentioned before generates $L(E,E)$ ?

Comment: because $A = \sum A_{i,j}E_{i,j}$!

Comment: okay! I still have some trouble with the end of the proof, I know that $E_{i,j}$ is the matrix which is equal to 1 if $i=j$ and zero else. But what is $E_{i,j}(e_{k})$ please?

Comment: no, $E_{ij}$ equals 0 everywhere except for index $(i,j)$ for which it is 1

Comment: ok, and what is its value at (i,j)?

Comment: thus, what I said in my previous post was right (you said "no..")

Comment: the condition is not $i=j$.

Comment: Actually my trouble comes from the definition of $E_{i,j}(e_k)$

Comment: what is your definition of $E_{i,j}(e_k)$ please?

Comment: it is in my answer. Please try to read carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a basis for $E$, we can represent operators in $L(E, E)$ by matrices in this basis.  Look at the matrices $E_{mn}$ such that $E_{mn}$ has the entry $1$ in the $m-n$ position and zeroes everywhere else.  They are linearly independent since $\sum \alpha_{ij} E_{ij}$ is the matrix $[\alpha_{ij}]$; it is zero if and only if $\alpha_{ij} = 0$ for all $i, j$.  This argument also shows how any matrix may be expanded in terms of the $E_{mn}$.  Thus the $E_{mn}$ form a basis for $L(E, E)$.  There are $n^2$ such $E_{mn}$; thus $\dim L(E, E) = n^2$.

***Edit:  Note in response to comment of Dror:***  If $A \in L(E, E)$ with basis $\mathbf e_i$ of $E$, then we have $A(\mathbf e_i) = \sum \alpha_{ij}\mathbf e_j$ for some matrix $[\alpha_{ij}]$, and any such matrix determines a linear operator in $L(E, E)$ since it defines $A(\mathbf e_i)$; indeed we have

$A(\sum_i w_i \mathbf e_i) = \sum_i w_i A(\mathbf e_i) = \sum_i w_i \sum_j \alpha_{ij} \mathbf e_j = \sum_j (\sum_i w_i \alpha_{ij}) \mathbf e_j; \tag{1}$

the matrix $\alpha_{ij}$ operates on vectors of components $(w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n)$ on the right; the components $w_i$ form a "literal" vector; it's a duality thing.  And since the vectors $\mathbf e_i$ are given *in abstracto*, it matters little in what space they lie, just so it is of finite dimension.  Vectors, matrices, tensors, the basic idea is the same.  ***End of Note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @Dror:  see my revised post.

Comment: @Dror:  thanks for garlic and onions!  And the tomatoes and avocadoes!  And of course, the ranch dressing!  Now I *am* hungry! ;-)!

Comment: @Dror:  you brought up salad!  And nutition!  Just following up on your metaphor!  Need further explanation?

Comment: Robert let's continue the discussion? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13711/discussion-between-dror-and-robert-lewis-continued